# Check if array contains element in D

Tags: arrays, d

for associative arrays we can write

```
if( elem in array) { .. }
```

what do we write for a simple array?
I want to write validation e.g.

```
enforce(input in [10,20,40]);
```

Comment: For ``enforce(input in [10,20,40]);``, you could alternatively use std.algorithm.among, like so: `enforce(input.among!(10, 20, 40));`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`in` sadly doesn't work on array. You must use `canFind` or `search` defined in `std.algorithm` http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html. Since you only want to know if it's present, not where it is, `canFind` is the right tool.

```
import std.algorithm: canFind;

if (my_array.canFind(42)) { stuff }
```

Comment: To clarify, ``in`` works for associative arrays and not regular arrays in D due to how they're implemented. An associative array is actually a hash table, meaning that the time complexity of ``in`` for AAs is O(1). For normal arrays, the time complexity of ``in`` would be O(n), because it has to traverse through the array to find the element you're looking for. The D community decided that it was not a good idea to have an operator that can be O(1) or O(n) depending on the container, so ``in`` can only be used with AAs (and any user-defined containers that implement opIn).

Comment: I can't this `search` that you said is defined in `std.algorithm`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to canFind, there is also countUntil which will get you the index of the first occurrence.

Note that D's "in" keyword searches the associative array's keys and not its values :

```
string[string] array = [
    "foo" : "bar"
];

writeln(("foo" in array) != null); // true
writeln(("bar" in array) != null); // false
```